# Jackson: Parent class Properties are ignored: Deserializes json into data

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to convert the JSON(myJson.json) object into Java Class.

Using the following [How to convert Java Object to From Json Jackson @Mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) code.

```
  //2. Convert JSON to Java object
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   StudentInfoDTO student = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\myJson.json"), StudentInfoDTO.class);
```

But the above `ObjectMapper` is `unable to map the Parent(StudentDTO) Class Properties(loggedInUser,createdBy,...).`

Are there any `@annotations` which can map the Parent Class Properties as well.

Any suggestions are welcome.

I am having the following - StudentInfoDTO, AddressDTO, StudentDTO, SkillsDTO and myJson.json.

**StudentInfoDTO:**

```
public class StudentInfoDTO extends StudentDTO implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private AddressDTO address;
private String studentName;
....getters and setters

}
```

**AddressDTO:**

```
 public class AddressDTO implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private Long zipcode;
    ....getters and setters

    }
```

**StudentDTO:**

```
 public class StudentDTO implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String loggedInUser;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdTs;
    private String updatedBy;
    private Date updatedTs;
    private List<skillsDTO> skills;
    ....getters and setters

    }
```

**myJson.json**

```
 {
   "address": 
      {
        "street": "Hunterfly Place",
        "city": "Dunlo",
        "state": "Arizona",
        "country": "Colorado",
        "zipcode": "1631",
      },
    "studentName": "John",

    "loggedInUser": "Admin",
    "createdBy": "System",
    "createdTs": "03-19-2011 14:53",
    "updatedBy": "John",
    "updatedTs": "06-11-2014 08:00",
    "skills": [
        {
            "skill": "Football",
            "grade": "A"
        },
        {
            "skill": "Swimming",
            "grade": "C"
        },
        {
            "skill": "Dance",
            "grade": "A"
        }]

    }
```

**My Error Log:**

```
03:29:03,132 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "loggedInUser" (Class com.mySchool.project.services.StudentInfoDTO), not marked as ignorable
03:29:03,133 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)  at [Source: c:\myJson.json; line: 51, column: 23] (through reference chain: com.mySchool.project.services.StudentInfoDTO["address"]->com.mySchool.project.services.StudentInfoDTO["loggedInUser"])

03:29:03,133 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)

03:29:03,134 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:246)
```

Comment: which library version you are using? I'm not facing any issue.

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis This is what i have in my pom.xml `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.5</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis I am with JDK1.7 and Jboss 7.1.1 and jackson 1.8.5

Comment: I think you have not added proper getters and setters for all classes.Please cross check it.Specifically in `StudentDTO` class

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis i had the Getters and Setters

Comment: Please can you post all the  classes code ? I'm not getting any exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65139/discussion-between-vishvesh-phadnis-and-09q71ao534).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the in-convenience.

It worked as expected.
I had an error in my `myJson.json` file and i had re-generated the Getters and Setters as suggested by `@Vishvesh Phadnis`

```
{
   "address": 
      {
        "street": "Hunterfly Place",
        "city": "Dunlo",
        "state": "Arizona",
        "country": "Colorado",
        "zipcode": "1631"
      },
    "studentName": "John",

    "loggedInUser": "Admin",
    "createdBy": "System",
    "createdTs": "03-19-2011 14:53",
    "updatedBy": "John",
    "updatedTs": "06-11-2014 08:00",
    "skills": [
        {
            "skill": "Football",
            "grade": "A"
        },
        {
            "skill": "Swimming",
            "grade": "C"
        },
        {
            "skill": "Dance",
            "grade": "A"
        }]

    }
```

Thanks all:)